# My Minecraft isn't launching

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My Minecraft says that my computer is low on memory and then says:

> save your files and close these programs: Java(TM) Platform SE binary

But I've looked for that program and I couldn't find it, what should I do?

Comment: Minecraft is written in Java. If you execute Minecraft, Java will be executed too. You can try to reduce the amount of ram your Minecraft/Java is using at the moment.

Comment: How much ram do you have and how much is being allocated to Java?

Comment: Try adding more ram. http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/unmodified-minecraft-client/tutorials-and-faqs/1871637-tutorial-allocate-more-memory-for-minecraft

Comment: It's fantastic how the difference between a upvoted and downvoted question is so low. It matters in 90% only on the first vote it got.

Answer (score 1):

At least 1GB of RAM is recomended to properly execute Minecraft.

1. Check [this](https://www.java.com/verify/) website to verify if your Java is properly installed (might not work on google chrome).
2. Follow the guide posted by @[MadMrCrazy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254203/my-minecraft-isnt-launching#comment405124_254203) to increase your allocated RAM to Minecraft.
3. **Alternatively**, uninstall your current Minecraft and reinstall with the latest installer from Mojang in [this link](https://minecraft.net/download). This brand new installer comes with a pre-packed Java that should make things easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

Open Task Manager by right-clicking the windows icon in the lower left and clicking Task Manager. Next, click on 'more details' and find Java Platform SE binary, click on it and click 'End Task'

Answer (score 0):

It might be because it is actually low on memory, or it might be for something else. Because we don't know what memory do you have (like if you run a x32 bits OS), I suggest you run a test on [System Requirements Lab](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri/requirements/minecraft/11356) and add to your question the number of GB of RAM that you have and the architecture of your operating system.

Also, you might want to prevent some apps from starting at the startup of your computer. Use the [Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Manager_(Windows)) in Windows 10 to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You do realize that Java SE Binary is the Minecraft window, right? Minecraft runs on Java. It's telling you that Minecraft is taking up too much space and you need to close it down. I would download like CCleaner or save some of the files that take a LOT of space into an online drive and delete them from your computer. Just try to free up as much space as you can.

Comment: Deleting files frees up disk space, not memory.

Comment: Lol I apologize. I forgot that they were separate.